# IE7 Not rendering the site correctly

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser, rendering, invisible

I have a Wordpress site(http://www.skalafitness.com). This website is rendering properly in all Major Browsers including IE8+. The only issue I am having is with IE7. The content area is completely blank and out of its place. The text is invisible (present in html source code). The sidebar, header and footer sections are displayed correctly. I've added the following meta statement but it doesn't help:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />`

Any Idea why this is happening? There is nothing much wrong with site html, it shows only one two errors from my site, rest are from social widgets.

Comment: How would IE7 be expected to emulate IE8 when IE8 didn't exist when it was programmed? 'EmulateIE8' is for IE9+ to use older behaviour.

Comment: @ceejayoz: I got your point. But that doesn't answer my question. Can you find anything wrong with the html or css that is causing the site to break in IE7?

Answer (score -1):

Just emulate IE7, not IE8.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

Comment: Why would IE7 emulating IE7 do anything?